# How to Silence Items in Sytem Notification

Tags: kubuntu, notification, notification-area

I have two notifications that haunt me on Kubuntu 13.10, and I would like for a way to suppress them, at any cost.

1.) `Connection 'Netgear18' deactivated!`

This comes from my crappy wireless card driver constantly de- and re- authenticating (known issue with the Broadcom 4313, but it works well enough for me to give up)

2.) `Bell Session in Shell`

My media player ncmpcpp sometimes throws a bell session when it switches songs, and I don't need to hear about it!

Removing the system tray just causes the notification to show up somewhere else on the screen. In a fit of rage I killed KNotify, but it respawns. Can I tell it to ignore certain types of message?

Comment: Thank you! As per the top answer, I went to `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` and found a file called `org.kde.knotify.service`, so I renamed it to `xxx.disabled`. I think I'm in business!

Comment: Welcome. But please try to search before asking to minimize duplicate questions

Comment: Duplicate questions are good in the sense that it makes answers easier for people to find. As long as the duplicates are using different terminology. For example, I couldn't find the question you linked because I wasn't using the terminology "notification-bubbles"